# Gerrit does not trigger my jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, gerrit

I have installed Gerrit 2.8 and configured it with two users (my local developer machine and jenkins) and imported an existing repository based on this guide:

https://review.openstack.org/Documentation/install-quick.html

I have cloned the gerrit repo with:

```
git clone ssh://user@gerrit-test:29418/repo_test
```

committed some changes and pushed them to gerrit with:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

I see the changes in the gerrit web UI. I have then installed:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger

and configured a maven job based on the above instructions:

[image]

And:

[image]

But when I push a change to gerrit the job is not triggered. I can trigger the changes manually from the **Query and Trigger Gerrit Patches** page though.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the user have the [Stream Events](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html) permission?

Comment: This was introduced with Gerrit 2.7

Comment: How I can give these permissions? i have Gerrit 2.9.1

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you set "Submit Type" as "Fast Forward Only" in your Gerrit Project Options.